# Two time fields, change the second one when first one is set

Tags: jquery, date

I have two time fields in a form. I am using [Clockpicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) for setting the time fields. The first of the two time fields is a start time, the second a end time. Before the start time is changed, I need to get the difference between the two time fields and when the start time has changed, I need to automatically in-/decrement the end time field based on the difference I calculated.

jQuery ClockPicker has two events that are suited for this:

`beforeHide` - fires before ClockPicker is hidden (after time has changed)
`afterShow` - fires after ClockPicker is shown (before time has change)

I need to be able to use localization for at least de-de (24-hour format) and en-us (12-hour format with AM/PM)

Here's my code (no localization support yet)

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
$('.clockpicker-start').clockpicker({
beforeHide: function () {
    $('#activitystartfield #StartTime').val($('.clockpicker-span-hours:visible').html() + ':' + $('.clockpicker-span-minutes:visible').html() + ' ' + $('.clockpicker-span-am-pm:visible').html());
    $('#activityendfield #EndTime').val(end - start);
},
afterShow: function () {
    var hour = $('#activitystartfield #StartTime').val().split(':')[0];
    var minute = $('#activitystartfield #StartTime').val().split(':')[1];
    start.setHours(hour);
    start.setMinutes(minute);
    hour = $('#activityendfield #EndTime').val().split(':')[0];
    minute = $('#activityendfield #EndTime').val().split(':')[1];
    end.setHours(hour);
    end.setMinutes(minute);
}
});
```

This gives me the difference in seconds, but I have no idea where to go from here or how to handle localization.

Comment: my specific question is calculating the difference between start and end time and after that adding that timespan to the end time so the difference between the two stays the same after start time has been set.

Comment: make a fiddle.. but it sounds like a matter of simple arithmethic...

Comment: i don't understand why you're calculating the 'difference' after only field has been inputted (and entering it in the end time field? you should have a separate text box or span tag to display the difference). Wait until both have been entered and then calculate the difference

Comment: let me rephrase it: start time is initialized as 13:00, end time as 14:30. the difference here is 90 minutes. when the user now sets a new start time, let's say 14:00, the end time field should automatically jump to 15:30. that's why I need the difference before any changes are made to both fields. when the user selects a new end time, nothing should be changed, that's part of my requirement. also, no other input fields should be used. sorry for my bad wording.

Comment: I noticed that one of my selectors were wrong, here is new jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/leonidasfettikus/g5frc55m/6/

Comment: think you should refer to this https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker/pull/40 also see http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jLj7pwj8/ Note that a function for comparing 2 times in clockpicker is an open issue https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker/issues/30

Comment: hmmm if I try to get the time like this: $('#end').clockpicker('getTime'); I get the DOM element back

Comment: ok never mind, I just figured out that I needed to manually download the changes from GitHub as they weren't included in the latest release (when I download the zip through the "Download ZIP" Link)

Comment: congratulations.. hope you sorted it out. :)

Comment: I still have some trouble adding the seconds back to my end date but I think I can manage from here. :) thanks for being so patient. if you want, you can post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: could you make a fiddle of what you have so far (you can include the js/css in the 'external resources' panel). Its only 9am here and as I'm off for the week I'm only up, but will have a look in a few mins..

Comment: Ok got it, I confused myself a little and got my logic mixed up: https://jsfiddle.net/leonidasfettikus/2uxck2Lb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm so sorry for my delayed reply; I was out earlier.

I tweaked a couple of things in your fiddle. First, I made the end input disabled until the user had inputted a start time. I removed the readonly attribute (you need to be remove it to be able to read the updated values I discovered). 
I added both an `afterShow` and `afterDone` to both start and end clockpickers
I didn't get around the AM/FM bit but i added a span which is updated with a display of the time difference (hours and mins) to the user

I discovered en route that if the mins were over 30 that the hour went onto the next hour so there's an if statement in the code to check for this

Here is [current code](https://jsfiddle.net/1njqkbu0/) - i tried to create a snippet and SO froze on me, so this is second go. Will try again in a while.

Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var start = new Date();
  var end = new Date();
  var difference;

  $('#start').clockpicker({
    donetext: "Done",

    afterShow: function() {
      start = $('#start').clockpicker('getTime');
      console.log('Start after show: ' + start);
    },
    afterDone: function() {
      start = $('#start').clockpicker('getTime');
      console.log('Start after done: ' + start);
      $('#end').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });

  $('#end').clockpicker({
    donetext: "Done",

    afterShow: function() {
      end = $('#end').clockpicker('getTime');
      console.log('End after show: ' + end);
    },
    afterDone: function() {
      end = $('#end').clockpicker('getTime');
      console.log('End after done: ' + end);
      difference = (end - start);
      getdiff(difference);
      console.log('Difference: ' + difference);
      console.log('Difference: ' + difference / 1000);
      console.log(difference / 1000 / 60);
      console.log(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    }
  });

  function getdiff(s) {
    var secs = Math.round(s/ 1000);
    var modsecs = ((Math.round(s/1000))%60); //remaining secs if not even
    var mins = Math.round(s/1000/60);
    var modmins = ((Math.round(s/1000/60))%60); //mins remaining if not even
    var modhrs = ((Math.round(s/1000/60/60))%24); //mins remaining if not even
    
    var hrs = Math.round(s/1000/60/60);
    if (modmins >=30){
        modhrs = modhrs-1;
    }
    
    var enddiff = [
      modhrs
    ];
    var arr = jQuery.map(enddiff, function(modhrs) {
      return modhrs + ":" + modmins;
    });
    $('#diff').text("Difference is " +arr);
  }
});
```

```css
.clockpicker-popover {
  width: 300px;
}

.clockpicker-button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/weareoutman/clockpicker/gh-pages/src/clockpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/JordyMoos/clockpicker/6f0ac5f0eb07b5302ebbc4ed7fd5b312c8fae224/src/clockpicker.js"></script>

<input id="start" val=" " data-default="09:00" />
<input disabled id="end" val=" " data-default="19:00" />
<br><br>
<span id="diff" val=" "> </span>
```

Comment: thank you for all your help. I will check your code, especially that over-30-mins-part. couldn't have done it without you. :)

Comment: @LeonidasFett no problem :) happy to help !

Comment: @LeonidasFett btw, this updated fiddle returns x hours and y mins https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/5mzacf8m/